# Css transition animation visible on load

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I have a css animated element. You can see the effect in the demo by clicking the checkbox.

In the demo the css is probably put inline so the issue is not shown in the demo. It only shows if the css is loaded from a css file.

#### Element visible on load (which it should not be)

What happends to me is that the red sidebar becomes visible for a short time before it animates away on load.

How can I get around it?

(I don't want any javascript in this case)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-in;
}

input:checked ~ div {
  margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="hello" type="checkbox">
<div>
adasdsaas
</div>
```

Comment: you need to load the CSS as soon as possible to avoid FOUC: https://petrey.co/2017/05/the-most-effective-way-to-avoid-the-fouc/

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your css file before page rendering using [rel="preload"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)

```
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="preload" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I'm surpriced but that did not work in Chrome, latest.

Comment: ok then try to add inline-style: <div style="margin-left: 100;">adasdsaas</div> and then set margin-left: 0 with 'important' on 'input:checked' to overwrite the inline-style.
 'input:checked ~ div {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
}

Comment: That is kind of what I ended up doing, thanks! I created a <style> element with the "reset" value.